# Save each month, each week etc. MongoDB logic

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to logically solve an issue of mine regarding data that is being read from an API and inserted into MongoDB.

Let's say I have a field called "apples", that changes in amount from month to month, due to seasonal effects, and I want to record these changes up to 6 months back, what do I do? Obviously I can't save new values for months that have passed, but looking forward, what can I do to save Novembers value for November and then Decembers value for December?

I would like to use NodeJS for this btw.

Sorry if I am unclear, it was even hard to explain!

Kind regards,
Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group things together. There is this thing called [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) in mongodb. 
There are a lot of things which you can do with it and one of them is grouping. 
More on that you can read in [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html)

You can insert each apple (document) separately for the given date. 
So for example:

- In "2017-11-26T16:00:00Z" we have 6 apples and price 15
- In "2017-11-25T16:00:00Z" we have 4 apples and price 16
- In "2017-10-25T16:00:00Z" we have 9 apples and price 30

## 1

Lets say we have these three entries:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1adc774d8a2fe38bec83e4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-26T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 6,
    "price" : 15
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1adc924d8a2fe38bec83e8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-25T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 4,
    "price" : 16
}
/* 3 */
{
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-25T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 9,
    "price" : 30
}
```

Now we want to group them by month and sum the apples per month we could do the following:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
{
    $project: 
    {
       month: { $month: "$date" }, 
       apples: 1, // here we just assign the value of apples. There is no change here
       price: 1 // also just assigning the value to price. Nothing is happening here.
    }
},
{
    $group: // grouping phase
    {
        _id: "$month", // This is what we group by 
        monthApples: {$sum: "$apples"} // here we sum the apples per month
        monthPrice: {$sum: "$price"} // here we sum the price for each month
    }
}
])
```

In the `$project` we can make use of [date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).

The above aggregation pipeline would result to this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 10, // month (October)
    "monthApples" : 9 // sum of apples
    "monthPrice" : 30 // sum of price for month 10
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 11, // month (November)
    "monthApples" : 10  // sum of apples
    "monthPrice" : 31  // sum of price for month 11
}
```

---

## 2

Now imagine we have the apple type also saved in the database.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1adc774d8a2fe38bec83e4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-26T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 6,
    "price" : 15,
    "appleType" : "Goldrush"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1adc924d8a2fe38bec83e8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-25T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 4,
    "price" : 16,
    "appleType" : "Pink Lady"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1b1c144d8a2fe38bec8a56"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-25T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "apples" : 9,
    "price" : 30,
    "appleType" : "Pink Lady"
}
```

We could group for example by apple type like that.

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
{
    $project: 
    {
       apples: 1, // here we just assign the value of apples. There is no change here
       price: 1, // also just assigning the value to price. Nothing is happening here.
       appleType: 1
    }
},
{
    $group: // grouping phase
    {
        _id: "$appleType", // group by appletype
        monthApples: {$sum: "$apples"}, // here we sum the apples per month
        monthPrice: {$sum: "$price"} // here we sum the price for each month
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly the kind of setup I'd want to use. I will into this asap. Thanks a lot Alex!

Comment: How do I group the documents if I don't have a specific date-field but rather just the _id? Tried to rewrite the aggregate-function above but it seems like it never runs. I'm using mongoskin as the driver btw!

Comment: what is the `"_id" `. If you mean the field `_id` then this is always unique for every document. It makes no sense to group by it, because you wont find any other document with the same `_id`. You can group them by anything that makes sense in your application. Imagine we had people with a field age. And we wanted to group people by age so we can see how many people we would have per age. So you have to think in your case, what makes sense to group by.

Comment: Is your _id in a format like that? `ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")`. If you could add a dummy example of how your database schema is. I could help you better.

Comment: my bad, thought we were grouping by date! Since the _id can be translated to a date-value, I thought we could use that.

I have changed the function above but when running it with node it just hangs there. When running it in shell I get "can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date", due to a field that isn't formated correctly...

Comment: Here is an example of a collection, with just four fields for clarity:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0e04cb9ce70c569699d1fb"),
    "created_at" : "2016-04-20T18:16:22Z",
    "updated_at" : "2017-11-16T21:35:46Z",
    "apples" : 1672
}

Comment: I'm afraid `created_at` and `updated_at` are of type `string` instead of type `date`. If you are flexible into changing your db schema, then convert your dates to (date)[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date]. You can leverage of the (date aggregation operators)[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/] and everything is easier if you use it the way it's supposed to be. Also here the question is on which field would you like to group now?

Comment: Well if we can ignore the wrong dates somehow (they don't really contribute to anything) I would just group by apples I guess? I do have some other fields that are always the same (specific string) that I could if needed.

Comment: I updated the answer with a second part. Take a look at it. If not then better ask another question since it seems to deviate from your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way to model this data will be creating a document for each product that will store it's pricing history for a month:

```
{
    product: "apple",
    amount:[  
     {day: ISODate("2017-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"), price: 24},
     {day: ISODate("2017-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"), price: 20},
     {day: ISODate("2017-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"), price: 19}, 
     {day: ISODate("2017-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"), price: 25} 
],
   quality: "best"
}
```

Comment: This was going to be my approach at first, but since I would have a lot of days with the same value it felt unintuitive to create a bunch of documents for no real reason. I think the approach Alex gave me made more sense so to speak. Thanks a lot for your input though!